# I want this R1C1 Formula to have a IFError( ),"0". But it wont work

Tags: excel, vba

I want this R1C1 Formula to have a IFError( ),"0". But it wont work.
¿Can Sombody help me add that to my formula in a correct way?

```
For J = 5 To 21
    For i = 1 To 20

        JuntarInfo.Range("O" & (J + 42)).Offset(0, i) = "=(R" & J & "C" & (15 + i) & "/ R" & (J + 21) & "C" & (15 + i) & ")"
    
    Next
Next
```

FYI (The formula I placed just above dose work perfectly.)

Comment: Try: `"=IFERROR(R" & J & "C" & (15 + i) & "/ R" & (J + 21) & "C" & (15 + i) & ",0)"`

Comment: Btw, it's best to specify that you're writing an R1C1 formula by using `.FormulaR1C1` after `Offset(0, i)`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! @Rory Thank you very much, and thnaks for the tip bigben.

Rory, I belive you answerd as a coment and not as an answer, if you want you can wrigt the answer and I can validate it, so you can have more points.

Comment: Instead of using _both_ `Range` _and_ `Offset` you can just use `Cells`, i.e. `JuntarInfo.Cells(j + 42, 15 + i).FormulaR1C1 = ...` 1 less property used = 1 slightly faster loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
JuntarInfo.Range("O" & (J + 42)).Offset(0, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(R" & J & "C" & (15 + i) & "/ R" & (J + 21) & "C" & (15 + i) & ",0)"
```

I included the explicit call to `FormulaR1C1` that @BigBen mentioned